# Refreshing ListView each time I search a new term

Tags: android, listview

I am using google book API to search a book with the title.It shows me the result for the first time. The next I search it clears the ListView but not showing the new search result.
There is a peculiar error. When I search a book it shows me  3 to 4 books whereas I have set MaxResult to 10. When I manually call the API in the browser I get 10 results.

Here is the code I am using.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<List<Book>>{

    private static final int BOOK_ID = 1;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    private static String book_url;

    private BookAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search);





        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText searchTerm=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_book);
                String search=searchTerm.getText().toString();

                book_url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+search+"&maxResults=10";

                LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
                loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_ID, null, MainActivity.this);

                mAdapter=new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this,new ArrayList<Book>());
                ListView bookListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                bookListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            }
        });
    }

    public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int i,Bundle bundle){
        return new BookLoader(this,book_url);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Book>> loader,List<Book> books){
        mAdapter.clear();
        if(books!=null&&!books.isEmpty()){
            mAdapter.addAll(books);
        }
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Book>> loader){
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

I tried notifyDataSetChanged(). But it doesn't work.

Here is the code for custom adapter

```
package com.example.android.booksearch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by AKSPAN12 on 19-07-2017.
 */

public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

    public BookAdapter(Context context, List<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0,books);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View listItemView=convertView;
        if(listItemView==null){
            listItemView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_list,parent,false);
        }

        Book currentBook=getItem(position);

        String author=currentBook.getAuthor();
        TextView authorView=(TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        authorView.setText(author);

        String bookName=currentBook.getBook();
        TextView bookView=(TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_name);
        bookView.setText(bookName);

        return listItemView;
    }


}
```

Comment: make your listview object global and please provide the code for your adapter.

Comment: i added the adapter code

Comment: Who uses ListView still? Heard of something called RecyclerView?

Comment: will using Recyclerview make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

> It shows me the result for the first time. The next I search it clears the ListView but not showing the new search result.

You probably need to [restart your loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting).

Comment: n where should i do that?

Comment: Probably where you're calling initLoader now. Your initLoader call should go in onCreate.